# Karate tests not working in headless mode since chrome updated to version 110.0.5481.104

Tags: google-chrome, karate

The failing tests are a set of regression tests that were developed a year ago.

When chrome is downgraded to version 109.0.5414.77 the regressions tests pass.

I'm using karate version 1.2. Any ideas what's changed in chrome?

Comment: absolutely no idea. chrome is known to behave "differently" in headless mode, so maybe you should use the docker container. we welcome any research from the community or pull requests, but right not this is not considered a priority, sorry !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.